# Free Disk Space running low over night (Win 7)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, disk-space

I noticed the last days that I got mysterious warnings on low disk space and I can't determine what occupies my free space.

So last night I had 5GB of free space and this morning I'm down to 800MB. And I have no clue what's going on here. I noticed that problem a couple of days ago, and because of that I did a scan with WinDirStat, to check what occupies the most space.
I got some virtual machine images that are pretty large, but consistent in size. also I got the pagefile and hibernate, but they did not change either. As far as I can see the biggest files did not change.

Also WinDirStat tells me that actually only 63.7GB are used, whereas the Windows dialog tells me 73.5GB are used.

I also ran a windows search on all file modified or created between yesterday and today but there was nothing that could be responsible for a 4GB space loss.

It also happened before that the occupied space becomes free again after a couple of hours or days. But I can't find a pattern in that...

Comment: How large is your hard drive? Do you have Windows update set to automatically download and apply patches?

Comment: my hard drive is 74.4GB in total. The update policy is set on Install important updates automatically on Wednesday nights.